# How to correctly wrap a php variable inside html tags?

Tags: php

I am not really expert in php, what I want to do is wrap the $duration variable in the last line inside a span tag, so I can style it.

```html
  <?php
$duration = '';
if( function_exists( 'cbc_get_video_data' ) ){
    global $post;
    $video = cbc_get_video_data( $post );
    if( $video ) {
        $duration = $video->get_human_duration();
    }
}
$title_content .= '<div class="post-title-wrapper"><h1 class="post-title">' . $duration . get_the_title() . '</h1>';
?>
```

when I do something like this the site breaks

```html
  <?php
    $duration = '';
    if( function_exists( 'cbc_get_video_data' ) ){
        global $post;
        $video = cbc_get_video_data( $post );
        if( $video ) {
            $duration = $video->get_human_duration();
        }
    }
    $title_content .= '<div class="post-title-wrapper"><h1 class="post-title">' . '<span class="video-duration">'$duration'</span>' . get_the_title() . '</h1>';
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 2nd example you are missing a `.` either side of `$duration`. You also aren't closing off a `<div>` and don't need the additional concatenation between the opening span.

To refine this code, try the following:
`$title_content .= '<div class="post-title-wrapper"><h1 class="post-title"><span class="video-duration">' . $duration . '</span>' . get_the_title() . '</h1></div>';`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the div was closing in another concatenation, I didn't put here the whole code.